# Having trouble in finding out what ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6 > 1 means? when sorting jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, tablerowsorter

i am having trouble finding out problem in my jtable sorting mechanism ,when ever i implement sorting inside the search code it gives me array index out of bounds , the populate table code works fine at intial stage but after the search happens it is also stuck.

My application has a text field area which accepts keywords for searching from database. Now after searching ,it displays it on jtable and i want to provide table sorter for that. Any help is appreciated . thks . I have also provides the stack trace below.

//problem code

```
// for searching data from data base and display it in table
// according to the keyword typed.

private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       

    System.out.println(evt.getKeyCode());

    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "cust_ID", "Title 2", "Title 3"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
    jTable1.removeColumn(jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));
    String query = "SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_address FROM employee WHERE emp_name LIKE '"+jTextField1.getText()+"%' ";
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:EazySource");
    Statement psmt = con.createStatement();
    //smt.setChar(1,"a");
    int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
    ResultSet result = psmt.executeQuery(query);
    int i = 0;
    DefaultTableModel model = null;
    while(result.next()){


        jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(Integer.toString(result.getInt("emp_id")), i, 0);
        jTable1.setValueAt(result.getString("emp_name"), i, 0);
        jTable1.setValueAt(result.getString("emp_address"), i, 1);

        model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        model.insertRow(jTable1.getRowCount(), new Object[]{null, null, null, null, null});
        String s1 = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
        System.out.println("id: "+s1);
        i++;
    }
    model.removeRow(i);
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter 
                    = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(jTable1.getModel());
    jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);
    for(String val:s){
        jTextField1.setText(val);

    }
    con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    }
}                                      
//initially populating table when app starts
public void populatetable(){
    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "cust_ID", "Title 2", "Title 3"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
    jTable1.removeColumn(jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));
    String query = "SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_address FROM employee ";
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:EazySource");
    Statement psmt = con.createStatement();
    //smt.setChar(1,"a");
    int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
    ResultSet result = psmt.executeQuery(query);
    int i = 0;
    DefaultTableModel model = null;
    while(result.next()){


        jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(Integer.toString(result.getInt("emp_id")), i, 0);
        jTable1.setValueAt(result.getString("emp_name"), i, 0);
        jTable1.setValueAt(result.getString("emp_address"), i, 1);

        model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        model.insertRow(jTable1.getRowCount(), new Object[]{null, null, null, null, null});
        String s1 = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
        System.out.println("id: "+s1);
        i++;
    }
    model.removeRow(i);
    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter 
                    = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(jTable1.getModel());
    jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);
    for(String val:s){
        jTextField1.setText(val);

    }
    con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

My stack trace ,can't figure what 6>1 means here

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6 > 1
    at java.util.Vector.insertElementAt(Vector.java:594)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(DefaultTableModel.java:374)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(DefaultTableModel.java:389)
    at javanotepad.NewJFrame.jTextField1KeyPressed(NewJFrame.java:174)
    at javanotepad.NewJFrame.access$000(NewJFrame.java:29)
    at javanotepad.NewJFrame$2.keyPressed(NewJFrame.java:82)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6463)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1890)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:752)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1017)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:889)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:717)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
8
8
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5718)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:684)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:581)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:365)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:276)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: It means there is 1 element in the `Vector`, and that you are trying to insert an element at position 6.

Comment: thks , got the answer,just had to make sorter null. thks to MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, please don't use `KeyListeners`, if you want this kind of action, use an `ActionListener` - there are 100's of reasons why, but for now, just trust us ;)

Try setting the sorter to null before changing the model

```
jTable1.setRowSorter(null);
```

I've usually encountered this problem due to a mutation event cause by multiple threads trying to update the model out of sync.

Comment: thanks a lot MadProgrammer , this solved problem .Also you said it correctly i was having that mutation problem. Yes i will try to use actionlistener from now on.

Comment: That's annoying problem, took me months to track it down :P

Comment: ya i was also smashing my head several times for this for past few days. :)

Comment: beware: it's a hack - should work with well-behaved threads. Keeping hacks in production code is ... suboptimal :-) Most probable culprit is that client code tries to access the table before its internal update is complete. To check, try to invoke the access (instead of nulling the sorter)

Comment: +1 kleopatra - the real solution is to make sure all UI code is only updated from the EDT

Comment: actually, I was wrong (or ... not entirely right :-) - see my answer, and +1 to yours

Comment: I had issues because the data been modelled coud be updated by any number of threads. While the update calls were synced back to the EDT, it meant that it was possible for the data & model to come out of sync (more rows had been deleted/added in the mean time). The solution was to batch the updates, rather then dribbling them as before - but that was make use case ;) - besides, no one solution is ever going to work all the time

Answer (score 2):

Digging a bit (as always when I have the time and something puzzles me :-)

First: @MadProgrammer's answer is correct - iff the client code takes responsibility to keep sorter and model in synch itself, instead of delegating that burden to the table.

Client code taking the burden:

```
TableModel model = .. //create some model;
table.setModel(model);
table.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(model));
// has to remove the rowSorter _before_ setting a new model
// because the old rowSorter still references the old model
table.setRowSorter(null);
TableModel newModel = ... // create some model ;
table.setModel(newModel);
table.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(newModel);
```

Let the table take care:

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter();
TableModel model = .. //create some model;
table.setModel(model);
// nothing to fear, simply set the new
TableModel newModel = ... // create some model ;
table.setModel(newModel);
```

BTW: in the OP's context, there is no need to reset the model - it's basically the same, just different data. So

```
// initially setting the model and rowSorter (in populate)
...
// in re-populating, instead of re-creating the same model 
//table.setModel(newModel);
// clear
((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).setRowCount(0);
...
// and - while we are at it - cleanup the logic 
while(result.next()) {
    Object[] rowData = {result.getInt("emp_id"), 
        result.getString("emp_name"), result.getString("emp_address")};
    ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).addRow(rowData);
}
```